# How to bind child objects of an object class to the GridView in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, oop, gridview, collections

I am building a Customer Service module for a project. I am storing all the complaints submitted by the users in the database and fetching them to display on the admin screen. My two entity classes which represent the complaint details and complaint raiser details are as follows

```
    public class Complaint
    {
        #region Fields of the class
        /// <summary>
        /// List of Complaints
        /// </summary>
        private List<Complaint> complaints = new List<Complaint>();

        #endregion

        #region Properties of the class

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Type { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string ActionTaken { get; set; }
        public bool Status { get; set; }
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
        public CSRInfo CsrId { get; set; }
        public ComplaintRaiserInfo complaintraiser { get; set; }

        #endregion

        #region Methods of the class

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets all the complaints from the List of complaints
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>Returns the list of the complaints</returns>
        public List<Complaint> GetComplaints()
        {
            return complaints;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Adds a complaint to List of Complaints
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="newComplaint"></param>
        public void AddComplaint(Complaint newComplaint)
        {
            complaints.Add(newComplaint);
        }

        #endregion

    }

    public class ComplaintRaiserInfo
    {
        #region Fields of the class

        public List<int> ComplaintIds = new List<int>();

        #endregion


        #region Properties of the class

        public FlightBooking BookingId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string MobileNo { get; set; }
        public string EmailId { get; set; }

        #endregion

        #region Methods of the class
        /// <summary>
        /// Gets all the complaint ids from the List of complaint Ids
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>Returns the list of the complaint ids</returns>
        public List<int> GetComplaintIds()
        {
            return ComplaintIds;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Adds a complaint id to List of Complaint Ids
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="complaintId"></param>
        public void AddComplaint(int complaintId)
        {
            ComplaintIds.Add(complaintId);
        }
        #endregion

    }
```

The data from database is fetched successfully and I am binding it to GridView in ASP.net Web Page as follows,

```
    ComplaintManager complaintManager = new ComplaintManager();
    List<Complaint> complaints = new List<Complaint>();
    complaints = complaintManager.GetComplaints();

    GridView1.DataSource = complaints;
    GridView1.DataBind();
```

My problem is that the properties of the Complaint class are displayed but the properties of the ComplaintRaiserInfo class are not displayed. Please help me to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could easily use LINQ to flatten the expression, which is commonly a problem with binding to the gridview:

```
var complaints = complaintManager.GetComplaints().Select((i) => new { 
  i.ComplaintID,
  i.ComplaintRaiser.ComplaintRaiserID,
  .
  .
});
```

This binds nicely to the grid.  You could try dot notation in the markup as in ComplainRaiser.ComplaintRaiserID for a templated field with an eval (haven't had success with the BoundField myself...)

Comment: Thanks for your solution, but I am instructed not to use LINQ in the project.

Comment: The GridView doesn't work with hierarchical data sources.  You can use template fields and `Eval("ComplaintRaiser.ComplaintRaiserID")` which may work... I've had  mixed results.  That would be your only bet, unless you want to create a hybrid class that contains the flattened results.  I would also ask why on LINQ because in this scenario it's doing nothing more than doing a foreach, which you can also use a foreach and add the anonymous type to an array list.